# How to add rows with missing dates after group by in Clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have table which looks like

| Number | State | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Number 1 | State 1 | Time 1 |
| Number 2 | State 2 | Time 2 |

and I want to write query to find out how many numbers was created in state by date for last week, so I wrote this:

```
select date_trunc('day', time) date,
       state,
       count(*) count
from table
where date_trunc('day', time) >= now() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
group by 1, 2
order by 1
```

But here is a problem: there is states which didn't provide data, and holidays when there wasn't any data provide
In the end I want to get table with all missing dates like this

| Date | State | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Date 1 | State 1 | 0 |
| Date 2 | State 2 | 100 |
| Date 3 | State 3 | 50 |
| Date 4 | State 1 | 0 |
| Date 5 | State 2 | 0 |
| Date 6 | State 3 | 0 |

The most important is that I can use only SELECT and can't join any other tables for finding dates without missing dates

I thought about creating table with every date of week cross join it with `select distinct(state) from table` and right join to my query, but don't know what to do with dates. Maybe you know how to do it other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only SELECT in the Clickhouse database, you can create a column-a range of dates

```
SELECT timestamp_sub(day, arrayJoin(range(0, 10, 1)), today())
```

then write a query connecting this column with dates with the data you want to see.

Instead of 10, write the number of days you need, and instead of today(), write the start date you need.